# I want to hide all the li's child except the i (fontawesome icon);

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to hide all these `li` when I style my navbar for smaller screen sizes that's why I only want to keep the fontawesome icon and hide all the `li`.

```css
li:not(i) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
</ul>
```

But after applying this code it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! do you want to hide text only?

Comment: Your current css will always hide all the li-elements since li-element cannot be i-element at the same time. That is why your :not will not do anything.

Comment: You can do one thing conditional rendering,  render only icons based on condition(for mobile) it will works.

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

> I want to hide all these li when I style my navbar for smaller screen sizes

A few solutions :

- Add a `span` around the text

```css
li span {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  li span {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Home</span></li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Home</span></li>
</ul>
```

Use `font-size: 0`

```css
li {
  font-size: 0
}

li i {
  font-size: initial
}


@media(min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    font-size: initial
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that solves the problem which is to hide the list elements. But it's also possible the poster is not being clear about what he wants.

Comment: This should be enough for the OP, given the snippet provided by OP

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter the HTML.

You can set the font-size to be 0 for the whole li and then set the font-size of the i elements to whatever you want.

```css
li {
  font-size: 0;
}

li i {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
</ul>
```

[Note, the snippet doesn't show the brand icons only a square as I haven't linked to latest versions].

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `font-size:0` for the `li`, and set it back for the `i` inside. In desktop, set it back to `initial`.

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
}
li i{
  font-size: initial;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
  li{
    font-size: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<ul>
  <li class="first"> <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"> <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"> <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"> <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the text into `<span>` element. Add a class to all those `<span>` so that you can specifically target them. Then using a suitable width in media query you can set `display:none` on them.

```css
/*choose your media query width*/
@media (max-width: 700em){ 
.first,
.second{
  list-style: none;
}

.icon-text{
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span class="icon-text">Home</span></li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span class="icon-text">Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span class="icon-text">Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span class="icon-text">Home</span></li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span class="icon-text">Home</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

*But Someone else showed it was possible using css selecting the inner children and lowering its font size.

Since it's not strictly possible using css, this is a solution using javascript and giving the chance to toggle text visibility saving its previous value on a data attribute of the parent element:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
   toggleTextContentVisibility();
});


function toggleTextContentVisibility(){
  const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');  
  lis.forEach((o,i)=>{       
    if (o.dataset.isvisible == 'false'){
      o.innerHTML += o.dataset.content;
      o.dataset.isvisible = 'true';
    }else{
      const textNode = o.childNodes[1];
      o.dataset.content = textNode.textContent    
      o.childNodes[1].remove();    
      o.dataset.isvisible = 'false';
    }        
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<ul>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="second"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="first"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>Home</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="toggleTextContentVisibility()">Toggle text content visibility</button>
```